# Does the Unix command Timeout also kill any children of the process?

Tags: bash, unix

The [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) for the 'timeout' command makes it seem that it kills child processes if it is not used with the '--forground' option, but I can't find any explicit definition of how it behaves.

Does the timeout command also kill child processes/a process group of whatever command is used with it?

Comment: There's not just one standardized `timeout` command -- there are different commands by that name, written by different people, with different behaviors. That said, if you're only asking about the (relatively recent) GNU coreutils implementation, that does narrow things quite nicely.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the coreutils implementation. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: To be clear, killing the group doesn't **guarantee** that every child will die, because children can intentionally put themselves in a new group (or just ignore the default SIGALARM). If you want a bit more certainty (against any program not going to fairly extreme countermeasures like closing all inherited FDs above and beyond stdin/stdout/stderr), better to use a lockfile and use something `fuser -k` to kill everything with a file descriptor on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GNU coreutils version of `timeout` can have its implementation viewed [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/timeout.c;h=98c064a18d54e64e151d8340b8151f9b00240885;hb=HEAD).

Whether a process group is created (and killed as a whole) does indeed depend on whether `--foreground` is passed, as you have inferred from the documentation.

---

To be a bit more explicit:

- When `--foreground` is **not** used, we call `setpgid()` to create a new process group, putting both the `timeout` command itself and the invoked command inside that group. When the timeout later occurs, `kill()` is passed `0` as the PID to kill, specifying that the entire process group should be targeted.
- When `--foreground` **is** used, only the immediately forked PID is signaled, and not other members of the process group.